# Show data in datagridview in selected dynamic tab c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to show data in **datagridview** in every tab that I have dynamically created earlier. However, the data doesn't show up.

This is my code.

```
private void DisplayLevel2Murid()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Jenis", typeof(string));

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HP\SQLMUS;Initial Catalog=KARYA;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            int i = 0;
            int tab = 0;
            con.Open();
            string[] names = new string[6];
            query = "SELECT Jenis FROM PengolahKata GROUP BY Jenis";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MuridTabLevel2.TabPages[tab].Text = reader[0].ToString();
                    names[tab] = reader[0].ToString();
                    tab++;
                }
                con.Close();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Need more info. Where you are using the `DataTable dt` and what you are doing with the `string[] names`? Not getting data on the DGV or also on the TabPage text?

Comment: i need to display data from my sql table onto my datagridview programmatically. However, i'm not able to show the data at all tabs. I use string[]names to dynamically create all the tab names. DataTable dt is the datagridview but no data shown. @nishithanair

Comment: Please confirm again. Each tabpage will have the unique 'Jenis' as its text and then you want to show all the data for that 'Jenis' in the gridview inside that tab?

Comment: `DataTable` is not `DataGridView`.

Comment: what i mean is at every tab, i want to show that particular tab's data. every tab should actually display different data. @nishithanair

Comment: If still not solved, please add full including the one that sets tab's text property and grid datasource. With the part of code given above, tough to figure out what you are doing wrong.